# Add a class on jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am newbie to jQuery. I have a form like this

```
<select name= "menus">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
```

Now I need that when I will click on "a" ,it will make an input field just in another  where there it should come like

```
<input type="text" name="a" />
```

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

**[edit]**
In this way more number of field can be added  at a time just like this code

```
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<input type="text" name="c"/>
<input type="text" name="d"/>
```

Comment: Can you give a more precise example to aid our understanding?

Comment: Are you saying you have 1 `input` control which you would like to change the `name` of, or multiple `input`s of which you want to add a class depending on the `name` matching the selected value from the `select`?

Comment: <select name="menus">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
There are multiple options on which when user will click it will just make an input field in an another <div> like <input type="text" name="" />
where the input name will be the same as the option value name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name="menus"]').change(function() {
        // fetch the selected value from the dropdown
        var value = $(this).val(); 

        // find the input element with name attribute equal to 
        // the selected value from the dropdown and add some class to it
        $('input[name="' + value + '"]').addClass('foo');
    });
});
```

When the dropdown list selection changes we add the `foo` class to the corresponding input element:

```
<input type="text" name="a" class="foo" />
```

And here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2G8RH/1/).